# Facebook comments plugin via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

I've Facebook Comments plugin in my website and if I simple refresh the page all works normal, but...

- everytime i load a new page via Ajax the plugin blinks and then disapears 
  (using FB.XFBML.parse(), if not, nothing appears).

I could work around that by removing the .fb_hide_iframes class {left: -10000px;} 
but the iframe receives a fixed height value, i.e: style="height:100px;" - so basically, the box is cut in a half and it won't be dynamic as if I reloaded the page)

- If I remove the .fb_hide_iframes and set a bigger height value to the Iframe, besides getting the big blank space, the "Load More Comments" of the box won't work.

Important Note: .fb_hide_iframes class doesn't appear if I simple refresh the page - all works normal

i've tried everything, but nothing worked, so i'm asking your help...
is there any other solution you guys can think of?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and was able to solve it by including a separate javascript file with the following:

1. A function which calls the FB.XFBML.parse() on ajax complete (which you currently seem to have in place already).
2. Also include the fb js within the same file, and outside of any document.ready functions (see below).

```
(function($) {
    // This function is what gets called on ajax complete.
    // Note: ajax complete part is not in this example.
    $.fn.fb_comments_refresh = function(data) {
        if (typeof FB != 'undefined') {
            // Refresh comment box.
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
// Needed for fb ajax modal to work repeatedly.
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));
```

This file needs to be called within the ajax-requested page.